# Security precautions to take, related to the `pivotal` user, after installing Chef (12)?

Tags: security, permissions, passwords, chef-infra, default-value

I've just installed Chef (12), on a public facing server, along with the Chef Manage interface.

The user `pivotal` is created by default, but I can't find any obvious information about the security considerations, which are crucial for public web services.

As far as I see, it's not possible to login to the web interface.

Is there anything that needs to be performed on such user, after installation (eg. change password, rename it, disable permissions, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That user is magic and internal to Chef Server. You will never touch it directly or be able to see it unless you do something very wrong like copying superuser authentication keys manually to a workstation.